# Passing a list of keys to SQL server through Powershell around 350 and returns result only for 68 - Need solution like left join in SQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am passing a list of 350 users and it goes to the database and find only 68 and returns result set only for those 68. I want it should return the result like it works for left join in SQL..like for those users where there is no match in DB it should return as "NA" or any char passed by me including the remaining matching results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments to the other answer, it sounds like the easiest thing for you to do is to tweak your powershell script.  See the below for an example.

When I need to do things like this, I usually create a function to return an empty object with the properties that I want to hold.  Then I create an array to hold all of them ($UserList in the below) and then for each user in your case, I would create a new $User (from Get-UserObject), edit the properties and add it to the $UserList variable.

Then you can query $UserList and do whatever else you require.

```
Function Get-UserObject {

    $O = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $O | Add-Member -Name "ServerSource" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value ""
    $O | Add-Member -Name "UserName" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value ""
    $O | Add-Member -Name "IsInSQL" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value ""

    Write-Output $O

}

$UserLIst = @()

#Repeat this bit for every user/query...
$User = Get-UserObject
$User.ServerSource = "ServerName"
$User.UserName = "John Smith"
$User.IsInSQL = "Result of Query, N/A, etc."

$UserLIst += $User 

#Finish Repeating list.
#Now you can manipulate $UserList like any other array of objects, query it, etc.
$UserLIst | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.IsInSQL -eq "NO"} | Format-Table 
$UserLIst | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL query you can left join to the full user list and replace the NULL values with your default string there. Then Powershell doesn't have to deal with the problem. Something like

```
select
  u.UserName
  coalesce(t.ExtraInfo, 'NA') as ExtraInfo
from InputUserList as u
left outer join SomeTable as t
  on t.UserId = u.UserId
```

Comment: Actually inputusers list is not stored at one place,hence i am using powershell to collect list of users from multiple servers around 12 and then pass them one by one to fetch the data for specific user from diff servers or same server

Comment: So, cannot use this left join in SQL query

Comment: OK, well do the above for each server and concatenate the lists in Powershell. Somehow you must be able to match the user value you have in Powershell to the user information in the database.

Comment: Can i chat with you ?